# Merge dataframes in pandas

Tags: python

I have two dataframes in python

1)salespersoncount

[image]

2)salesdata

[image]

I want to merge both tables on country and repeat salesdata no of time value of salesperson in salespersoncount and repeat this n times which will be an input and the final output should look like:

[image]

Can anyone please guide on above steps?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a join like so:

```
salespersoncount.join(salesdata.set_index('Country'), on='Country')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='Country',right_on='Country',how='inner')
x=x.loc[x.index.repeat(x['SalesPers'])]
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.